# Discrete metric space is nonseparable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

Can someone shows me how to prove that a discrete metric space is non separable? Now I know that 'non separable' means the metric space does not contain countable dense subsets, but I just can not see how to solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: (a) You probably mean an uncountable (as a set) metric space? (b) Hint: What is the the closure of any set in discrete topology?

Comment: Please edit your question in light of comments by @zipirovich.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume, as pointed out by zipirovich in the comments, that your metric space $X$ is uncountable as a set. Well, suppose we take a countable subset $A\subset X$. Because we are working in the discrete topology, $\overline{A}=A$, and thus $\overline{A}\subsetneq X$ because $X$ is uncountable, while $A$ is countable.

As such, no countable dense subset can exist. Note, however, that in the case where $X$ is countable, $X$ is a countable dense subset of itself and the exercise becomes trivial.